# Unknown (possibly malicious) behaviour when executing .mkv file

Tags: windows-10, malware, matroska

**Context**:
I was transferring files from my phone to laptop through USB. I was curious about one of the videos in the Telegram folder (which had a .mkv extension) and double clicked. Now normally when I execute a video file on my phone through my laptop, it opens in VLC almost immediately. However, I had only opened .mp4 files before. This was the first time I've opened a .mkv file. (My laptop runs on Windows 10 Home)

**Behavior**
This time, a windows dialog box opened up which said "Downloading to XYZ". I immediately closed the dialog box, deleted the folder and disconnected the USB.

I understand that this might just be my PC downloading the file to a temporary folder to play it. But I have never encountered this before. I tried searching up online for any documentation of such behavior, but was unable to find anything. I have heard of malware attacks using vulnerabilities of the .mkv extension and I fear that this might be the case.

Is this just normal and harmless behavior? If not, what do I do now to secure my laptop and phone?

Comment: Is VLC registered as the handler for `.mkv`?

Comment: @harrymc yes, it is.